# correctly retriving multiple values from database, java phone app --- php local server

Tags: java, php, variables, split, httprequest

So I am creating an application that has to grab data from a mysql server, using php and java.
I've got a backgroundworker reading lines into a result string.
I want to return the result not as a single string, but broken up into the echo'ed values called.

the rundown is as follows:
the java phone application scans a barcode - pulls the mysql database row that unique barcode is in, displays the other barcodes from that row (up to 7), gets a bool check for inuse or !inuse by the user, then updates that row. the function is to remove barcodes from being 'inuse' where they can be recycled into the system.

my question is - what is the best way to separate the line into multiple variables, or is there some way to separate the lines by \n line, or is it something I need to explode outside of the background worker?

just really fuzzy working with php and java together...

so far not much: if I find a good solution I'll post it here...

```java
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

String result = "";
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    result += line;
}
```

```php
case($option) {
    case 1:
        while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['barcode1'];
            echo $row['barcode2'];
            echo $row['barcode3'];
            echo $row['barcode4'];
            echo $row['barcode5'];
            echo $row['barcode6'];
            echo $row['barcode7'];
            echo $row['proccessed'];
            echo $row['materialkey'];
        }
```

there are no errors yet, just not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please clarify the question to outline which application is doing what. It looks like the java code sent "something" to php over http that then goes to the database and produces output, but that wasn't clear in your description, only inferred from your code.

Comment: 1 - grabs a string - sends that to php, where it does a sql query for the corresponding database entry where that barcode exists.
2 - each of the barcodes returned get placed as text next to a switch recording a bool - the user mark any still in use barcodes using a switch.
3 - the on/off state of the switch, gets sent to a php script to remove the correct barcodes.

the question: the end of step 1 and before step 2... returning the database row as separate objects to store into these switches... best method?

so... general pattern looks like find->change->update

Answer (score 0):

I will do my best to answer your exact question: What is the best way to separate the line into multiple variables.

Your initial assertion is correct, splitting the string on \n via readline on stdin would be the simplest answer.  When stdin is at the "end of file," you can stop parsing variables.  This should work without to much trouble, but I would not consider it the "best" approach due to its fragility.

Just model the PHP response as an array or object and then use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to send it back to the app.  The json can also be validated on the app end with [json schema](https://json-schema.org/) as well as parsed with the [countless](https://www.json.org/) client libraries.

```
$a = [
    "barcodes" => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "processed" => false,
    "materialkey" => "?"
];

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($a);
```